# Creating LaTeX math macros within Sphinx

Tags: python, macros, latex, python-sphinx

I'm writing some mathematical code in Python and using Sphinx to produce the documentation. I know that Sphinx can handle LaTeX code in Python docstrings; see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.mathbase. How can I create LaTeX macros, such as `\newcommand{\cG}{\mathcal{G}}`, to use in the Python docstrings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha, i found a solution that works with the Sphinx pngmath extension. It's the trick that Sage (open source mathematics software) uses; inspiration from http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/misc/latex_macros.html.

To add your own Latex macros to a Sphinx document:

1) Make a file, say 'latex_macros.sty', containing your macros (one per line), and put it in, say, the same directory as your Sphinx conf.py file;

2) Add the following code to your Sphinx conf.py file:

```
# Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
latex_elements['preamble'] = '\usepackage{amsmath}\n\usepackage{amssymb}\n'

#####################################################
# add LaTeX macros 

f = file('latex_macros.sty')

try:
    pngmath_latex_preamble  # check whether this is already defined
except NameError:
    pngmath_latex_preamble = ""

for macro in f:
    # used when building latex and pdf versions
    latex_elements['preamble'] += macro + '\n'
    # used when building html version
    pngmath_latex_preamble += macro + '\n'

#####################################################
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using MathJax, here's a possible solution. I'm still looking for a nicer solution, but it might help if you need a quick hack.

1. Create a file under the directory specified in the `html_static_path` configuration option (typically `_static`), say `mathconf.js`. This will contain the JS configuration for MathJax. For instance (from the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/TeX.html)):

   ```
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
     TeX: {
       Macros: {
         RR: '{\\bf R}',
         bold: ['{\\bf #1}', 1]
       }
     }
   });
   ```

   You can add more commands following the syntax above. The contents shown define the macros `\RR` and `\bold{#1}`, this last one accepting one argument.
2. Add a `layout.html` file at the `_templates` directory. The idea is to extend the current theme, so it searches the previous MathJax configuration file. Thus, the contents are:

   ```
   {% extends "!layout.html" %}
   {% set script_files = script_files + ["_static/mathconf.js"] %}
   ```

   Note that in this case it *is* the `_static` directory, because in this case it refers to where to search *after* the build. Sphinx will have moved the file from `html_static_path` to the `_static` directory under the build directory.

Comment: Didn't work for me (sphinx=1.3.1) probably because I can't set the script type correctly to `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> src="_static/mathconf.js"></script>` (see 
http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options).

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Keta's answer since Aug 2018 and this commit (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/5230/files) you can use `mathjax_config` in the conf.py according to the documentation (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html?#confval-mathjax_config)

So for example the following can be added,

```
mathjax_config = {                  
    "TeX": {                        
        "Macros": {                 
            "RR": '{\\bf R}',       
            "bold": ['{\\bf #1}',1] 
            }                       
        }                           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the pngmath extension, you can put that in the preamble by inserting this into the conf.py script:

```
pngmath_latex_preamble = r"\newcommand{\cG}{\mathcal{G}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution tested on sphinx-doc 2.4.3 (e.g., `sphinx-quickstart --version`)

Sphinx-doc allows additional tweak with MathJax through [mathjax_config](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html#confval-mathjax_config). The end goal is we want to implement the following in `conf.py`:

```
mathjax_config = {
    'TeX': {
        'Macros': {
            # Math notation
            "Z": "\\mathbb{Z}",                                    # set of integers
            # MoA notations
            "minus": "{}^{\\boldsymbol{\\mbox{-}}\\!}",            # scalar negation operator
        }
   }
}
```

We can do so manually like above. However, we can do better by automatically populate `mathjax_config` via parsing a separate `.tex` file that contains all the macro commands.

For example, I have `mathsymbols.tex` sits in the same level as `conf.py` with content looks like below:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ojoin}{\rule[-0.12ex]{.3em}{.4pt}\llap{\rule[1.2ex]{.3em}{.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\leftouterjoin}{\mathrel{\ojoin\mkern-6.5mu\Join}}
\newcommand{\rightouterjoin}{\mathrel{\Join\mkern-6.5mu\ojoin}}
\newcommand{\fullouterjoin}{\mathrel{\ojoin\mkern-6.5mu\Join\mkern-6.5mu\ojoin}}
```

Then, inside `conf.py`, we can write:

```
mathjax_config = { 'TeX': {'Macros': {}}}

with open('mathsymbols.tex', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        macros = re.findall(r'\\(DeclareRobustCommand|newcommand){\\(.*?)}(\[(\d)\])?{(.+)}', line)
        for macro in macros:
            if len(macro[2]) == 0:
                mathjax_config['TeX']['Macros'][macro[1]] = "{"+macro[4]+"}"
            else:
                mathjax_config['TeX']['Macros'][macro[1]] = ["{"+macro[4]+"}", int(macro[3])]
```

to automatically populate `mathjax_config` and we're done.

With the above example, we can use `\leftouterjoin` LaTeX macro inside sphinx-doc.

Comment: This answer is great! however, I needed the following modifications to make it work for me: (1) change `mathjax_config` to `mathjax3_config`; (2) lowercase the config dict keys: `{'tex': {'macros': {}}}`. In addition, I also added `renewcommand` to the regex.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great modifications for mathjax!

Answer (score 0):

If HTML+MathJax is the only output format, the following works in plain Docutils out-of-the-box:

```
.. math:: \newcommand{\half}{\frac{1}{2}}
          0.5 = \half

With MathJax, we can use the macro later: :math:`\half+\half=1`.
```

With LaTeX, the `\newcommand` definition is local to the first equation.