# Making Sphinx detect changes to auxiliary configuration/template files

Tags: python, configuration, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx (v1.4.9, with Python 3.5.1 on Windows 7, 64-bit) to write a document set with MathJax enabled.  I wanted to define custom LaTeX commands to clean up my source, so I implemented [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728292/creating-latex-math-macros-within-sphinx/19268549#19268549) by adding `_templates\layout.html`:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% set script_files = script_files + ["_static/mjconf.js"] %}
```

and defining my custom commands in `_static\mjconf.js`:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      dsetarr: ['{\\small \\textsf{#1 Array } \\mathsf{(#2)} }', 2],
      dsettype: ['{\\small \\textsf{#1}}', 1],
      mtt: ['{\\texttt{#1}}' ,1],
      sgn: ['{\\mathrm{sgn}#1}', 1]
    }
  }
});
```

This is all working great.

***However***, whenever I edit `mjconf.js` to add a new command or revise an existing one, Sphinx doesn't recognize that the configuration has changed and so a simple `make html` doesn't rebuild the docs like it does after an edit to `conf.py`. I have to `make clean` before the `make html` in order to see the effects of the changes to these custom MathJax commands.

**How can I configure Sphinx to react to an edited `mjconf.js` by rebuilding the entire documentation set, just like it does for an edited `conf.py`?**

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. But doesn't `make clean html` solve the problem? It does rebuild the entire documentation set.

Comment: @mzhn Not on Windows. Windows's `make.bat` only takes one "make target" at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`make html -a`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-a), but that will not reflect updates to cross-references in your documentation. This would be the fastest option, though, if you have no cross-reference updates.

There's also [`make html -E`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-e) in case you have cross-references that must be updated, too.

Finally there is `make clean html`, which deletes (cleans) the build directory, if your makefile has it, then builds HTML again.

Comment: My Windows `make.bat` doesn't appear to handle anything other than a single "make target". None of these three options works: the first two just do a plain `make html`; the third does `make clean` and stops there. Maybe I need to bite the bullet and figure out the v1.5 upgrade? It behaved badly the last time I tried it.

Comment: Considering further, I should be able to edit `make.bat` so that it passes any further arguments directly to the Sphinx builder.... then `make html -E` would probably work. I'm *guessing* that `-a` won't regenerate deeply enough into the configuration, but I'll try it.

Comment: Yep, a quick hack of `make.bat` to add `%2` to the options passed to `sphinx-build` works nicely to allow both `make html -a` and `make html -E`. Both invocations incorporate my changes to `mjconf.js` just fine. Thanks!  (FWIW, I put together a [GitHub PR](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/3841) for Sphinx that enables multiple make targets (`make clean html epub latex`) and passing of ~arbitrary `sphinx-build` arguments, for the benefit of future generations.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable invocations such as `make html -E` as [recommended by Steve Piercy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43908388), I changed my `make.bat` from this:

```
set BUILDDIR=build
set ALLSPHINXOPTS=-d %BUILDDIR%/doctrees %SPHINXOPTS% source
set I18NSPHINXOPTS=%SPHINXOPTS% source
if NOT "%PAPER%" == "" (
    set ALLSPHINXOPTS=-D latex_paper_size=%PAPER% %ALLSPHINXOPTS%
    set I18NSPHINXOPTS=-D latex_paper_size=%PAPER% %I18NSPHINXOPTS%
)
```

to this:

```
set BUILDDIR=build
set ALLSPHINXOPTS=-d %BUILDDIR%/doctrees %SPHINXOPTS% source %2
set I18NSPHINXOPTS=%SPHINXOPTS% source
if NOT "%PAPER%" == "" (
    set ALLSPHINXOPTS=-D latex_paper_size=%PAPER% %ALLSPHINXOPTS%
    set I18NSPHINXOPTS=-D latex_paper_size=%PAPER% %I18NSPHINXOPTS%
)
```

**The only change was appending `%2` to the line initializing `%ALLSPHINXOPTS%`.**